# Copy tree directory from specific point

Tags: bash, directory, directory-structure, file-copy

I am now sure how to word this, but:

I am  copying all the newest .zip files each recursive sub directory inside this original folder:

```
"/Users/Stu/Documents/Hoffi Work/FTP Backup Shell Script/Original"
```

For example

```
"/Users/Stu/Documents/Hoffi Work/FTP Backup Shell Script/Original/test1/zip11.zip"
"/Users/Stu/Documents/Hoffi Work/FTP Backup Shell Script/Original/test1/zip12.zip"
"/Users/Stu/Documents/Hoffi Work/FTP Backup Shell Script/Original/test2/zip21.zip"
"/Users/Stu/Documents/Hoffi Work/FTP Backup Shell Script/Original/test2/test3/zip31.zip"
"/Users/Stu/Documents/Hoffi Work/FTP Backup Shell Script/Original/test2/test3/zip32.zip"
"/Users/Stu/Documents/Hoffi Work/FTP Backup Shell Script/Original/test2/test3/zip33.zip"
```

This would copy zip12.zip, zip21.zip, zip33.zip (these are the newest in each directory) to the backup folder.

I have this working so all of these copy to this directory:

```
"/Users/Stu/Documents/Hoffi Work/FTP Backup Shell Script/Backup"
```

So it looks like:

```
"/Users/Stu/Documents/Hoffi Work/FTP Backup Shell Script/Backup/zip12.zip"
"/Users/Stu/Documents/Hoffi Work/FTP Backup Shell Script/Backup/zip21.zip"
"/Users/Stu/Documents/Hoffi Work/FTP Backup Shell Script/Backup/zip33.zip"
```

I want it to use the same tree structure (from Original onwards) so it looks like:

```
"/Users/Stu/Documents/Hoffi Work/FTP Backup Shell Script/Backup/test1/zip12.zip"
"/Users/Stu/Documents/Hoffi Work/FTP Backup Shell Script/Backup/test2/zip21.zip"
"/Users/Stu/Documents/Hoffi Work/FTP Backup Shell Script/Backup/test2/test3/zip33.zip"
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Here is my code:

```
#THE DIRECTORY THE ORIGINAL FILE IS STORED IN
MYDIR="/Users/Stu/Documents/Hoffi Work/FTP Backup Shell Script/Original"

#THE DIRECTORY THE BACKUP FILE WILL BE STORED IN
DEST="/Users/Stu/Documents/Hoffi Work/FTP Backup Shell Script/Backup1/"

#FIND ALL DIRECTORIES AND NAME TEMP DIRECTORY AS CURRENT DIRECTORY
find "${MYDIR}" -type d | while read CURRENTDIRECTORY;
    do 

        #FINDS THE NEWEST ZIP FILE IN T HE DIRECTORY
        NEWESTFILE=`ls -dtr1 "${CURRENTDIRECTORY}"/*.zip | tail -n 1`
        echo "NF = $NEWESTFILE"

        #CHECK IF FILE IS PRESENT
        if [ -z "${NEWESTFILE}" ] ; then
            echo "No file to copy"

        #CHECK IF FILE IS A DIRECTORY
        elif [ -d "${NEWESTFILE}" ] ; then
            echo "Newest file is a directory"

        #COPY NEWEST FILE TO DEST
        else
            echo "Copying ${NEWESTFILE} --> ${DEST}"
            cp -p "${NEWESTFILE}" "${DEST}"
        fi

    done
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `rsync` instead of `cp`:

```
rsync -R "${CURRENTDIRECTORY}"/"${NEWESTFILE}" "${DEST}"
```

To limit the output path to be relative to `MYDIR` (for example `test1/zip12.zip`) you will have to enter the directory before find loop: `cd $MYDIR` and later `find .`.

If you keep old files in backup directory you could even replace the whole script using `rsync --ignore-existing`. It would only copy new files.

Read more in [man rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync).

Comment: Cheers, I will take a look!